# How should I map E'(Fp6) --> E'(Fp) starting from Bitcoin public key coordinates(x,y)?

Tags: dsa, cryptocurrency

Let $p$ be the prime number `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`
and let $E$ and $E'$ be the curve equations
$$E(\mathbb F_{p^6}) : x^3 + 7$$
$$E'(\mathbb F_{p^6}) : x^3 + 4$$

then, by sextic twist property, $E/\mathbb F_{p^6}$ and $E'/\mathbb F_{p^6}$ are isomorphic.

How should I map $E'(\mathbb F_{p^6}) \to E'(\mathbb F_p)$ starting from public key coordinates $(x,y)$?

Is this map the [Frobenius endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism)?　Do I need to derive for root $z$? To map through the follwoing sequence of points.

$$(x,y)\in E(\mathbb F_p), (x,y)\in E(\mathbb F_{p^6}), (z^2x,z^3y)\in E'(\mathbb F_{p^6}), (?, ?)\mathbb E'(\mathbb F_p)$$

In the following, $E(\mathbb F_p) \to E(\mathbb F_{p^6})$ can be the inclusion mapping. "=" is sextic twist isomorphism.

$$E(\mathbb F_p) \to E(\mathbb F_{p^6}) = E'(\mathbb F_{p^6}) \to E'(\mathbb F_p).$$

Comment: Your question would benefit from LaTex/Mathjax, see how [there](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). For example you can get $E'(\mathbb F_{p^6}):x^3+4$ as `$E'(\mathbb F_{p^6}):x^3+4$`. I notice that $p$ and $x^3+7$ match [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1), but I don't get the origin of $p^6$ and $x^3+4$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  x^3+4 and p^6 origin is https://web.archive.org/web/20230214162837/https://github.com/christianlundkvist/blog/blob/master/2020_05_26_secp256k1_twist_attacks/secp256k1_twist_attacks.md

Comment: I did not like the page, since they assumed the [inverse of the Lagrange Theorem is true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

Comment: Since they are isomorphic and prime order curves, you can set any element - except the identity - as the base element.

Answer (score 1):

The "natural" map from $E'(\mathbb F_{p^6})$ to $E'(\mathbb F_p)$ is the Frobenius trace map
$$(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)+_{E'}(x^p,y^p)+_{E'}(x^{p^2},y^{p^2})+_{E'}(x^{p^3},y^{p^3})+_{E'}(x^{p^4},y^{p^4})+_{E'}(x^{p^5},y^{p^5}).$$
If composed with the inclusion map this sends $P\in E'(\mathbb F_p)$ to $6P$, so you might wish to also multiply by the scalar 1/6.

Likewise, the natural map from $E(\mathbb F_{p^6})$ to $E'(\mathbb F_{p^6})$ is to find an element of $\mathbb F_{p^6}$ such that $\alpha^6=4/7$ then using the map
$$(x,y)\mapsto (\alpha^2x,\alpha^3y)$$
note that there are 6 different possible maps, but the Frobenius trace of the image point will be the same for all of them.

Note that in this case your composition map $E(\mathbb F_p)\to E'(\mathbb F_p)$ is homomorphic, but due to the incompatible group orders it therefore degenerates trivially.